# Browser renders differently on local machine and on test server (even css source code!)

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem. It is not even a problem, but I am not able to understand why it happens.

I am doing the following:

1) Open mycustom.url/test/assets/libs/bootstrap.min.css on chrome browser - verison of my website on test server

2) Open localhost/assets/libs/bootstrap.min.css on the same browser - the same version, but on my local machine

And what I see?! Browser renders both files in different way. Rendered from test server font seems bigger. Why?! It is simply css file source code.

[image: Image for browser difs]

**Here is how I get to this:**

I noticed the different on the webpage I am developing and first I thought that I made some css or js minification problem and I could not find it. Webpage seemed a little bit different if rendered from test server and when rendered on my local machine. Then I decided to see if versions of css file are the same on test and on local machine and I opened just css file source code in browser. And what I saw? Rendering is different. So the problem is not in my code, but why?

Comment: Try doing `ctrl + shift + r` a hard reload, this clears up the cache, maybe the files are stored in cache

Comment: try to `ctrl + 0` broswer size normal

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Can you describe why it was not size normal by default? It worked after ctrl + 0

Comment: normal size is default,but your hand apply `zoom-in'